# Extend Wordpress Plugin Class

Tags: php, wordpress, class, oop, extend

I’m quite new to OOP, learned the basic idea and logic and now want to extend a wordpress plugin which is not intended for extending it (as far as I can tell):

```
class Main_Plugin {
    ...
    function __construct() {
        add_action('admin_notice', array($this, 'somefunction');
    }
    ...
}
enter code here
new Main_plugin
```

So far so good. Now the code of my custom plugin:

```
class Custom_Plugin extends Main_Plugin {
    ...
}
new Custom_Plugin
```

From my understanding the object of the “main” plugin is initialized as well as my “child” plugin which means that the `admin_notice`.

Is there any way to create the “child” plugin correctly so that the “main” plugin is running and my custom plugin just adds some additional functionalities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to extends the `Main_Plugin` class, if you use `class_exists` to check if the main plugin class exists.

```php
 if(class_exists('Main_Plugin')){
      new Custom_Plugin;
 }
```

You can split your main class, one for what you need on every load, one to extend.

---

**EDIT:**

There is other way to trigger some custom datas in other class

In the `Main_Plugin`, you can define your own action/filter or use an existing one:

```
 $notice_message = apply_filters('custom_notice', $screen, $notice_class, $notice_message);// you need to define parameters before
```

In any custom plugin you'll be able to hook $notice_message easily:

```
public function __construct(){
    add_filter('custom_notice', array($this, 'get_notice'), 10, 3); 
}
public function get_notice($screen, $notice_class, $notice_message){
    $notice_message = __('New notice', 'txt-domain');
    return $notice_message;
}
```

Comment: Ok but if the main has contains another function like: 
`if ( $pagenow === 'wp-login.php' ) {
    global $error, $interim_login, $action, $user_login;
    @require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-login.php';
    die;
}`
it would not be possible to change this behaviour as my plugin runs after the main one right? I would have to write a plugin which runs before the main plugin just for this specific case and let the main plugin do the rest if the the situation does not fit my condition?

Comment: Yes that why i told you to split the class

Comment: Ok thanks. Even though I don’t want to change the original plugin (update overwritings, etc.) this helped me.

Answer (score 2):

You think in the right direction but in Wordpress it is better not to do different plugins with the same action name. Feel free to extend Main_Plugin class but please change you action name to another one and use it in your templates. So, your code will be looking like so:

```
class Custom_Plugin extends Main_Plugin {
    function __construct() {
      add_action('admin_notice_v2', array($this, 'somefunction');
    }
}
new Custom_Plugin
```

If you would like to completely override previous action then delete previous action and add your as is described here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40456/how-to-override-existing-plugin-action-with-new-action
If you would like to extend the action then just call parent action from your action

Comment: Sorry but I don’t think that this will help me… The Plugin does not influence my template and in my point of view wordpress action hooks are meant to be used multiple times. Let me explain it differently: I could use the remove_action function to prevent my plugin to display the admin_notive of the main plugin two times. But all the other functions will run again as the object of the main plugin is initialized before my plugin right? Is there a way to extend the main plugin and initialize the extended object alone?